# IntentService not getting Intents from manifest registration

Tags: android, intentfilter, intentservice

This IntentService (NotificationService in the snippet) isn't getting started and doesn't receive those Intents.  By registering a receiver for them in the Application class, I've verified that those Intents are being broadcast. I just want to get them when the app isn't started.

```
    <service
        android:name=".services.NotificationService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.redactedtoprotecttheinnocent.ACTION_INCOMING_CALL"/>
            <action android:name="com.redactedtoprotecttheinnocent.ACTION_CALL_STATUS_CHANGE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Any suggestions for what might be wrong here?  I'd rather not create a broadcast receiver just to start an IntentService.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any suggestions for what might be wrong here?

You appear to be thinking that services are started automatically by broadcast `Intents`, which is not the case.

> I'd rather not create a broadcast receiver just to start an IntentService.

Well, you are welcome to rewrite the code that is sending `com.redactedtoprotecttheinnocent.ACTION_INCOMING_CALL` and `com.redactedtoprotecttheinnocent.ACTION_CALL_STATUS_CHANGE` broadcasts, so that they stop sending broadcasts, and instead use `startService()` to send commands to your service. If this code is not yours, though, changing it may be difficult.

Or, you can have a short manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` that turns around and calls `startService()` to have the service process the broadcasts.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. I don't get to change how the call broadcasts come in, so it sounds like having a receiver that just starts the service is the way to go here.

Comment: @Turnsole: There are three channels on the quasi-message bus that is the `Intent` system: activities, services, and broadcasts. Messages on one channel (e.g., broadcasts) are only consumed on that channel. They only cross channels (e.g., broadcasts -> services) if you do the work to move them across the channels.